# Increase the wait time of Twilio messaging?

Tags: twilio

Let's assume a server has a lag in its internet network. Whenever, Twilio is attempting to message it, then the messaging are succceding 50% of the time , while the other 50% are failing because of HTTP: connection timed out.

Is there any way to tell TWilio to increase the wait-time or retry messaging the server?

Answer (score 2):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

You won't be able to increase the timeout on Twilio or have it retry but what you can do is check the response you get from Twilio using the [callback url](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/sending-messages#post-parameters-optional). That is obviously providing Twilio is able to make a request to your server at that time.

Twilio will then make a request to your server to tell you whether it was able to send the message or not.

You could then add those messages into a queue, and try to resend them later on.

What you could also do is use the API to get the error logs for your application, and try to resend the messages for any message that wasn't sent. Have a look at the [Events Monitor API](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/monitor/events) for this.

Let me know if this helps you.

Comment: Thanks for responding. 
If the internet for the server is shady, then rely on a callback url wouldn't be as reliable as well. 
Is there an automated response that can be setup on twilio side whenever a message has failed during transmission?

Comment: Unfortunately not, but you could always use the second option I gave you, which is querying the API logs and check for messages not sent. That way you will always guarantee your messages got sent at some point.